# Firestore rules, using short circuit to squeeze out reads

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Are these two Firestore rules different at all in the number of reads that they spend from my quota? Note that `isWebAdmin()` does an `exists()`, which eats away from my read quota.

```
// example 1
match /companies/{company} {
  // rule 1
  allow list, write: if isWebAdmin();

  // rule 2
  allow get: if isInCompany(company)
    // when isInCompany is true, this is short-circuited away
    || isWebAdmin(); 
}
```

vs.

```
// example 2
match /companies/{company} {
  // rule 1
  allow read, write: if isWebAdmin();

  // rule 2
  allow get: if isInCompany(company); 
}
```

Here is my (possibly faulty) reasoning: For most `get` requests `isInCompany(company)` will be `true` and `isWebAdmin()` will be `false`. Therefore, in example 2, even though the user is authorized to `get` with rule 2, rule 1 will also execute because `get` is also a `read`. So, while trying to give the admin access, I'm spending more reads for regular users who have access.

In example 1, I separate out `get` and `list` and treat them separately. In `get` requests, it will not run rule 1 at all. When running rule 2, since `isInCompany(company)` is true, `isWebAdmin()` won't execute because of short circuiting. So, in the common case I saved a read by avoiding calling `isWebAdmin()`.

Is this correct? If so, simply slapping admin privileges adds gets for each user's regular operation. I find this a bit inconvenient. I guess if this is not the case, we should be billed by only the "effective" rule, not everything that was tested. Is *that* the case instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Firebase security rules, boolean expressions do short circuit, which is a valid way of optimizing the costs of your rules.  Use the more granular rules in example 1 for that.

Comment: Noted you said Firebase; does this indicate intent for your statement to apply to both Firestore and Realtime Database? (or does rtdb even have similar document access limits?)